# Смена цвета для Rectangle в оверлее WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-5

Каким образом можно сменить цвет для Rectangle и обновить его в оверлее?
Я сейчас использую этот метод смены цвета:

```
static public Color w = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);
static public Color a = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);
static public Color s = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);
static public Color d = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);
static public void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics g, int size, int x, int y)
{
    // Background
    Brush bBrushW = new SolidBrush(w);
    Brush bBrushA = new SolidBrush(a);
    Brush bBrushS = new SolidBrush(s);
    Brush bBrushD = new SolidBrush(d);
    ...
```

Но при смене цвета, объект оставляет свой старый цвет, меняю цвет подобным образом в таймере:

```
private void Letters_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Keystokes W
    if (Input.isPressed(Keys.W) != 0)
    {
        Keystokes.w = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
    } else
    {
        Keystokes.w = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);
    }
    ...
```

Функция `Draw` вызывается всего один раз из Paint формы:

```
private void Overlay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;
    Keystokes.Draw(g, 50, Width - 350, 250);
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы цвет обновился при минимальных нагрузках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз, когда вам нужно обновить цвет:

```
Overlay.Invalidate();
```

Или лучше если известны координаты области которые надо обновить:

```
Rectangle area;  
Overlay.Invalidate(area);
```

И ещё лучше выбросить таймер и следить за клавиатурой:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookProc;
private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; // Номер глобального LowLevel-хука на клавиатуру
const int
   WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100,       //Key down
   WM_KEYUP = 0x101;         //Key up

//функция, принимающая нажатия
public IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)260)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam); //Получить код клавиши
        this.Text = "Нажата клавиша: "+vkCode; //this == form1
    }
    if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP || code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)260)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam); //Получить код клавиши
        this.Text = "Отжата клавиша: " + vkCode; //this == form1
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

//при загрузке формы подключаем слежение
form1.Load += (s,a) =>
{
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
};

//при закрытии формы отключаем слежение
form1.FormClosing += (s,a) =>
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook); //Остановить хук
};
```

На место "this.Text = ... vkCode; //this == form1" - подставьте нужный вам if-else по клавишам, а лучше функцию func(int vkCode), в которой и производить данную обработку с вызовом Invalidate()

Пример взят отсюда: https://www.cyberforum.ru/post9660429.html

Comment: До сих пор цвет остается неизменным

Comment: Overlay_Paint как часто вызывается? Invalidate() откуда вызывается?

Comment: Overlay_Paint вызывается один раз - при запуске.
Invalidate вызывается из Letters_Tick

Comment: До вызова Invalidate дело доходит? Точкой останова ловится?

Comment: До вызова доходит, я использую его в конце веткок if
Может проблема в том, что я не могу изменить переменную в другом классе `static public Color w = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35);`? Изменяю с помощью `Keystokes.w = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);`

Comment: После останова можно смотреть статические значения. Invalidate() обязан вызывать Paint(), если только обновление не заблокировано намеренно в Overlay. Overlay - контрол какого типа? Может ошибки какие-нибудь валятся в окне вывода в визуалке? Если Overlay - нестандартный контрол - нужно знать что это и что из себя представляет, может у него другие условия вызова отрисовки.

Comment: Overlay - форма WinForms

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123018/discussion-between-blackmeser-and-slavatar).